# How to convert string datetime of a Dataframe into Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am working with currently with a csv file that contains datetimes and timestamps. The dataframe look like this:

```
print(df[:10])

  [0 '2019-10-10 21:59:17.074007' '2015-10-13 00:55:55.544607'
 '2017-05-24 06:00:15.959202' '2016-12-07 09:01:04.729686'
 '2019-05-29 11:16:44.130063' '2017-01-19 16:06:37.625964'
 '2018-04-07 19:42:43.708620' '2016-06-28 03:13:58.266977'
 '2015-03-21 00:03:07.704446']
```

and now I want to convert those strings into datetime and find the earliest date out of it. I don't have much experience in datetime dataframes so I am not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like a list. What is the output of: `type(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call the list you mentioned `l`, you can iterate on it and parse dates using `datetime.strptime`, aggregate them in a new list and return the earliest:

```
from datetime import datetime

parsed_dates = []

for d in l:
    parsed_dates.append(datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
print(min(parsed_dates))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert strings `to_datetime`, then take `min`:

```
dates = ['2019-10-10 21:59:17.074007', '2015-10-13 00:55:55.544607',
 '2017-05-24 06:00:15.959202', '2016-12-07 09:01:04.729686',
 '2019-05-29 11:16:44.130063', '2017-01-19 16:06:37.625964',
 '2018-04-07 19:42:43.708620', '2016-06-28 03:13:58.266977',
 '2015-03-21 00:03:07.704446']

pd.to_datetime(dates).min()
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2015-03-21 00:03:07.704446')
```

---

**Update**

If you want to do it across all columns of the dataframe:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime).min().min()
```

Comment: I can't use that because I have many values in the dataframe (I think 100 columns and rows) and to_datetime does not work for a reason

Comment: Please see the update, it basically applies `to_datetime` column-wise, then takes `min` for each column, and then takes `min` among column minimums

Comment: And if only some columns of your dataframe are dates in string format, then you can, of course, do `df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_datetime).min().min()` (assuming the dates are in `col1` and `col2`

Answer (score 1):

Convert these value to datetime by using [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

```
df=pd.to_datetime(df,errors='coerce')
```

Now find earliest date by using [`min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) method:

```
earliest_date=df.min()
```

OR you can also find earliest date by using [`nsmallest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) method(This works on Series):

```
earliest_date=df.nsmallest(1)
```